# Gostaria de saber como faz para pegar o número de telefone com javaScript

Tags: javascript

O codigo que estou trabalhando.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("details-contact")[1].innerHTML
    
function abreLink() {
  var url = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55' + x + '&text=Ola%2C%20gostaria%20de%20saber%20mais%20sobre%20seus%20produtos%20e%20serviços.';
  document.write(url);
}
```

```html
<div class="details-contact">
  <div class="contact-item item-phone">
    <span class="icon icon-md">...</span>
    <a href="tel:(11) 2222-3333">(11) 2222-3333</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não coloque imagens, por favor. Se pretende apresentar o seu código copie e cole o mesmo. Caso contrário dificulta (e muito) para que outras pessoas lhe ajuem.

Comment: Conseguiu verificar a responsta?

Answer (score 0):

Fiquei na dúvida se respondia ao enunciado ou ao propósito do código...

Iniciando pelo propósito:

```js
function abreLink(link) {
  var url = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55' + link.text + '&text=Ola%2C%20gostaria%20de%20saber%20mais%20sobre%20seus%20produtos%20e%20serviços.';

  document.write(url);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="tel:(11) 2222-3333" onclick="abreLink(this); return false;">(11) 2222-3333</a>
```

Indo pelo código apresentado:
O uso de `getElementsByTagName` está incorreto neste caso, uma vez que você passa uma classe no lugar de uma tag html. O mais fácil neste caso seria adicionar um id ao link do telefone e usar o método `getElementById`.

```js
<a id="id_do_telefone" href="tel:(11) 2222-3333">(11) 2222-3333</a>

var phoneElement = document.getElementById("id_do_telefone").innerHTML
ou até
var phoneElement = document.getElementById("id_do_telefone").text
```